# Events Firing Unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Can you write code to tell an event not to fire? Sometimes in my applications events fire  unexpectedly. I know this is a broad question, but it must have happened to others out there.

Comment: What events are firing unexpectedly?

Comment: Also how is their firing "unexpected"? Have you subscribed to some OnChange event that fires when you change it in code as well as when the user makes a change? You need to give some more detail.

Comment: How would you cancel an event if you don't know what event to cancel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put an if-statement in your event handler around all the code or you could dynamically detach and reattach the event handlers from outside the event handler, if necessary.

But really, events don't just fire without reason.  You probably have something else going on.  Maybe you can explain more what the situation is?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to suppress an "unexpected" event. But you could remove all of the event handlers. This is rather drastic, but would be equivalent to suppressing the event.

Alternatively you could add code to the event handlers to do nothing when the event is fired unexpectedly. This assumes you can define "unexpected".

Rather than suppress an event, a better approach is to remove/suppress whatever is that's causing the event to fire.